# React Native - how to inspect the UI/ elements?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native

I have installed the react dev tool. But I can't see it my Chrome browser when I launch my app on the emulator.

[image]

If you watch this [youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rDsRXj9-cU), you can see the react tab is in the list and you can inspect your app's UI.

Any idea why?

How can I inspect the app's UI/ elements if the react dev tool is not working on my Chrome?

Comment: I think the best way to do it is CMD+ CTRL+Z(in your Simulator on Mac) open element inspector

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Devtools "React" is currently not possible. This is due to a change in how the application scripts are evaluated in the devtools plugin. You can see more at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#devtools-react-tab-does-not-work

However, you can still debug your UI within your application. To inspect elements, open your app in Simulator > press Cmd+D > select Show Inspector.

Comment: Hi, Is there way to make this built in inspector bigger? the image and texts appear after inspecting an element is too small

Answer (score 19):

Step 1: Install the react-devtools package globally using this command :
npm install -g react-devtools

Step 2: Goto your Project Directory and run project

Step 3: Open other command prompt and goto at Project Directory and run following command
react-devtools

Step 4: It will open "React Developer Tools"

Step 5: Now at Emulator press Ctrl+M and select Toggle Inspector

Step 6: Now you can inspect in React Developer Tools

for more information go at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

[image: React Developer Tools]

Comment: Hi, Is there way to make this built in inspector bigger? the image and texts appear after inspecting an element is too small

Answer (score 5):

1.Globally install

```
npm install react-devtools
```

2. If you get EACESS error because of permission problem then try with following command

   sudo npm install -g react-devtools --unsafe-perm=true

3.Then in our project directry give command

```
react-devtools
```

It will open separate app React Native deveveloper tools

4.copy the script from the app and paste it into our component and inspect it

Comment: paste it where exactly?

Comment: You could paste it at the very top of the component, even before importing React