# How to inspect elements in react native app development?

Tags: android, debugging, react-native

Actually i want to inspect element of my mobile app just like web apps in browser console. Is there similar kind of way that can help me for design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use React dev tools with react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581160/how-to-use-react-dev-tools-with-react-native)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - how to inspect the UI/ elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638245/react-native-how-to-inspect-the-ui-elements)

Answer (score 3):

On iOS: hit CMD + d
On Android: hit CMD + m

Then select "Toggle Inspector".